# Touching iAd banner affects UIImageView movement

Tags: uiimageview, iad, adbannerview

iAd works fine itself. When i click on iAd it loads a full screen ad. Then when i click out of iAd. and click on my start game button, the UIImageView in the game moves by itself in the direction depending on which side of the ad I clicked on. Don't know why touching the iAd affects UIImageView. I use a touchesBegan method to move UIImageView. What can I do to stop this iAd touch affect on UIImageView?

Used the following in VC.m to integrate iAd.

#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

     [banner setAlpha:1];

     [UIView commitAnimations];
}



-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

EDIT:

My `touchesBegan` method:

MoveLeft, moveRight, StopSideMove are all BOOL values in `ViewController.h`

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    moveLeft=NO;
    moveRight=NO;
    stopsideMove=YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{            
   UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
   CGPoint point=[touch locationInView:self.view];
   if (point.x <170) {
       moveLeft=YES;
   }
   else
       moveRight=YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `touchesBegan` method? I think there is something wrong.

Comment: What about the start game button? Is everything OK without the iAd?

Comment: The entire game works perfectly fine. The only issue is when the game starts the UIImageView automatically moves in the direction depending on what part of ad I clicked on. The only time the ad doesn't affect UIImageView during the game is when I close the ad and click anywhere on the screen first and then click start game and then UIImageView is not affected at all.

Comment: Does the UIImageView overlapping the ADBannerView ?

Comment: Only a moving background UIImageView is in back of ADBannerView. The UIImageView that moves on its own when game starts is at bottom of screen. Ad Banner is at top of screen. They never touch.

Comment: Try to change `locationInView:self.imageView`, while `touchBegan` will trigger in your whole view.

Comment: Or create a view which not including the ADBannerView and change the touchevent.

Comment: How do I go about changing the touchesBegan method for my ADBannerView  ADS outlet in a way that it doesn't affect UIImageView movement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67650/discussion-between-worldofwarcraft-and-mika).